# url downloads manually, but not with NSURLRequest

Tags: xcode, url

I think my problem is like the one [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782388/) but I cannot quite understand the answer.

My app requires users to enter the URL of a site that contains `.pbn` files. But the same URL which works manually, does not work when entered in the TextField in my app. In my example case `self.urlNameInput.text` is `http://www.atlantaduplicatebridgeclub.com/scorepost/2013/01/20130126ana.pbn` and the URL is not recognized.

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlNameInput.text] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                              timeoutInterval:60.0];
```

Depending on whether I include or exclude 'http://' I get the following error messages.

Connection failed! Error - A server with the specified hostname could not be found. http://www.atlantaduplicatebridgeclub.com/scorepost/2013/01/20130126ana.pbn

Connection failed! Error - unsupported URL www.atlantaduplicatebridgeclub.com/scorepost/2013/01/20130126ana.pbn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work just fine:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.atlantaduplicatebridgeclub.com/scorepost/2013/01/20130126ana.pbn"]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSString *results = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Results:%@", results);
}];
```

Comment: Yes, before I had the TextField I used the following successfully, too, but now I get problems with the TextField entry. `NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.atlantaduplicatebridgeclub.com/scorepost/2013/01/20130126ana.pbn"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];`

Comment: Thank you. I got the download to work, but I have a related question. Can I now eliminate the following delegate methods: connection:didReceiveResponse:, connection:didReceiveData:, connection:didFailWithError: and connectionDidFinishLoading: because you are using another route? Or can I somehow hook up your approach to those delegate methods?

Comment: [This answers my question about delegate methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181633/).